# What is "Radiation damping stronger than inertia."

Tags: photons, radiation, inertia, pulsars

I'm reading a paper on creating gamma rays in a lab and I've come across a phrase I simply don't understand; "Radiation Damping Stronger Than Inertia".

As I understand it radiation damping is just energy lost by radiation, but how does this relate to inertia in the context of photon rays?

Comment: It would be very helpful for the viewers if you provide link of the paper,if available.